# Initialize the automatically implemented properties in F#

Tags: f#

["Automatically implemented properties are part of the initialization of a type, so they must be included before any other member definitions, just like let bindings and do bindings in a type definition"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd483467.aspx)

But the complier doesn't complain if I put `member val` after other ordinary `member this.` properties in the type declaration. Is it all right?

Am I correct to say that the property is initialized when initializing an object, not when the property is first called?

e.g.

```
   member val = let printf "%A" "initializing"
                3 with get, set
```

So every time I create an object it will print "initializing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, the initialization code for automatically implemented `member` is run as part of the object construction (even if you put some other `member x.Bar = ...` declarations before the `member val`):

```
type Test() =
  do printfn "constructor"
  member x.Bar = 
    printfn "calling Bar"
    10
  member val Foo = 
    printfn "initializing Foo" 
    3 with get, set

let t = Test()
printfn "constructed"
t.Foo
```

The code in the constructor runs first, followed by the `Foo` initialization (the code in `Bar`, on the other hand, is not called until you actually call `t.Bar`), so this prints:

> constructor
>   initializing Foo
>   constructed